# IoTEdge sometimes re-creates the container

Tags: azure, azure-iot-edge

We're running IoT edge modules. Inside our module, we update bunch of files. We noticed that most of the time, if the host is restarted, the container is restarted and the files we updated still exist.
Very few times, however, we noticed that when the host restarted that the container is re-created from the original image thus all data changes were lost.

Our understanding is that iot edge is using docker restart policy = always which should always keep the data of the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have next suggestions:

1. do not store important data on the container writable layer => do not rely on the restart policy
2. the reason of rebuilding the container could be a new version of your module image which was deployed, so the container was recreated using new image
3. setup your module deployment manifest ([example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/module-composition#deployment-manifest-example)) properly by using the module container **createOptions** and attach a local volume to the container ([**createOptions->HostConfig->Binds**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-deploy-blob#configure-a-deployment-manifest)), and store your data there. This will survive any recreations of your module container . See [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-deploy-blob#configure-a-deployment-manifest). something like:

   `"createOptions": {
     "HostConfig": {
       "Binds": [
         "/app/db:/app/db"
       ]
     }
   }`